# How to make custom animated Container from button of the app till half of the app screen

Tags: flutter, dart, animation

expected behavior

[image]

i tried this code but it give me completely difference result from left side and strange animated

```
double val = 0;
    @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
        return   Stack(
          children: [
    
            Container(
              height: 400,
              color: Colors.red,
            ),
            TweenAnimationBuilder(
                duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 150),
                tween: Tween<double>(begin: 0 , end:  val) ,
    
                builder: (BuildContext context, double? value, Widget? child) {
    
                  return (
                      Transform(
                          alignment: Alignment.center,
                          transform: Matrix4.identity()
                            ..setEntry(3, 2, 0.001)
                            ..setEntry(0, 3, 200 * value!)
                            ..rotateY((pi/6)*value),
                          child:  DefaultTabController(
                              length: 5,
                              child: Scaffold(
    
    
                                  body:   Center(
                                    child: Container(
                                      color: Colors.yellowAccent,
                                      child: IconButton(
                                        onPressed: () {
                                          setState(() {
                                            setState(() {
                                              val == 0 ? val = 1 : val = 0 ;
                                            });
                                          });
                                        },
                                        icon: Text('tab me'),
    
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  )
    
                              )
                          )
                      )
                  );
    
                }
            )
          ],
        );
    
    
    
      }
```

also i need only the red Container the one who animated from down to up , but i don't know why the main screen is also animate .. i need it never animated ..

any suggestion most welcome guys .. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of custom animation, you can use `AnimatedContainer()`.

Create a boolean like `selected` which will tell the animated container when to close and when to open the container. And using `setState` you can toggle the animation.

Align your `AnimatedContainer()` with `Align()` and give `alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter`. And give `height:0` is not selected and when selected give height the half of screen using `MediaQuery.of(context)`

```
class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyStatefulWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyStatefulWidget> createState() => _MyStatefulWidgetState();
}

class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  bool selected = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(children: [
      ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            selected = !selected;
          });
        },
        child: Text("Tap Me!!"),
      ),
      Spacer(),
      GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          setState(() {
            selected = !selected;
          });
        },
        child: Align(
          alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
          child: AnimatedContainer(
            width: double.infinity,
            height: selected ? MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2 : 0,
            color: selected ? Colors.red : Colors.blue,
            alignment:
                selected ? Alignment.center : AlignmentDirectional.topCenter,
            duration: const Duration(seconds: 2),
            curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
            child: const FlutterLogo(size: 75),
          ),
        ),
      )
    ]);
  }
}
```

You can try the same code in dartpad [here](https://dartpad.dev/?id=690563a41dae00b320f7f7696e9179ae)

Comment: thanks a lot ,, that's what i want